# Determine .NET and CLR requirements for your PowerShell modules

Tags: powershell, module, manifest

Module manifests let's us specify requirements for .NET and CLR, sample from manifest ***.psd1**

```
# Minimum version of Microsoft .NET Framework required by this module.
# This prerequisite is valid for the PowerShell Desktop edition only.
DotNetFrameworkVersion = "3.5"

# Minimum version of the common language runtime (CLR) required by this module.
# This prerequisite is valid for the PowerShell Desktop edition only.
CLRVersion = "2.0"
```

I have several modules that I'm working on, and I'm unable to find some resources to help me out specify minimum versions that my modules require.

To solve this issue I'm thinking about writing a regex script that will scan modules for .NET types used, for example the script would harvest types such as:

```
[System.Net.IPAddress]
[System.Management.Automation.ValidateUserDriveAttribute]
```

And based on types used I could go check in what version of .NET and CLR were individual types introduced.

Then also I could run tests with older versions of PowerShell, but only with "Core" edition, I'm not sure if it's possible to install older Windows PowerShell.

This is all together a lot of work and I'm not even sure if that answers my concern, do you know of better method that could be used to learn requirements?

Comment: "I'm not sure if it's possible to install older Windows PowerShell." it's not, you can't have different versions side-by-side prior to 6/7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm thinking about writing a regex script that will scan modules for .NET types

It won't give you a complete picture but it's a good start!

One thing I'd emphasize though - don't use regex for this type of static analysis!

PowerShell exposes its language parser, so use that to produce an Abstract Syntax Tree instead, you can then use that to discover things like the name of type literals:

```bsh
using namespace System.Management.Automation.Language

Get-ScriptTypeLiteral
{
  param([string]$LiteralPath)

  $filePath = Resolve-Path @PSBoundParameters

  # Step 1, parse the file to produce an AST
  $AST = [Parser]::ParseFile($filePath, [ref]$null, [ref]$null)

  # Step 2, find all type literals
  $TypeLiterals = $AST.FindAll({
    param($SubAST) 
    # Type literals come in two variants - expressions and attributes 
    # Expressions are things like the first half of `[type]::Member`
    # Attributes cover things like [ValidateLength()] as well as type constraints in param blocks
    $SubAST -is [TypeExpressionAst] -or $SubAST -is [AttributeAst]
  }, $true)

  # Step 3, return the type names
  return $TypeLiterals.TypeName
}
```

You can take this approach further and use it to discover things like [member access expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.language.memberexpressionast) to take differences in BCL types across versions into account as well.

While I've never used it for this particular purpose, I suspect you could leverage [PSScriptAnalyzer](https://github.com/PowerShell/PSScriptAnalyzer) to simplify this process with custom rules.

> This is all together a lot of work and I'm not even sure if that answers my concern, do you know of better method that could be used to learn requirements?

I'm not sure I'd consider any of the above "best practice", but it might be worth submitting an issue asking for guidance on this in [the PowerShell GitHub repo](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues)

Comment: Thank you for good answer, I don't know much about .NET but will give it a try according to priorities and how easy it may be. PSScriptAnalyzer sounds like easy way to do this type of job.

Comment: @metablaster PSScriptAnalyzer already has a couple of built in rules for detecting compatibility for PowerShell language features, so if nothing else it can help you infer the minimum _PowerShell version_ requirements

Answer (score 0):

With the help of @Mathias answer I've done some research and come to solution that is very easy and some 90% accurate.

First step is to define rule for PSScriptAnalyzer, this rule should be defined in file `PSScriptAnalyzerSettings.psd1` and put it into root directory inside your repository.

The file should contain this rule:

```
@{
    IncludeRules = @(
    
    'PSUseCompatibleCmdlets'
    'PSUseCompatibleSyntax'
    
     Rules = @{

        PSUseCompatibleSyntax = @{
            Enable = $true
            TargetVersions = @(
                "7.0",
                "5.1"
            )
        }

        PSUseCompatibleCmdlets = @{
            compatibility = @(
                "core-6.1.0-windows"
                "desktop-5.1.14393.206-windows"
            )
         }
      }
   )
}
```

Then invoke analyzer from the root of your repository:

```
Invoke-ScriptAnalyzer .\ -Recurse -Settings .\PSScriptAnalyzerSettings.psd1
```

This will let you know whether your modules call any commandlets that are not compatible with Core 6.1 or Desktop 5.1

If you get warnings, these versions are not supported meaning need to perform tests on higher PowerShell versions.

Why is this important? it's about PowerShell versions not about .NET or CLR...
Also how could you test higher Windows PowerShell version if 5.1 is the latest one?

Well there is also a build number in above rule which is `14393`, for which problems may be reported, and the next step is to determine Windows version for this build, to do so see:

[Windows 10 release information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/release-information/)

From here we see that the build number is for Windows v1607.

Next step is look at which version of .NET is included in which versions of Windows, to do so see:

[.NET Framework versions and dependencies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/versions-and-dependencies)

From here we see that the minimum .NET version that get included into Windows 10 is `.NET Framework 4.6` which depends on CLR 4.0

At this point it all boils down on which systems your module is going to be deployed, and if you get warnings from PSScriptAnalyzer then the minimum is .NET 4.6 and CLR 4.0

Next step is to determine exact OS build number for which your modules fail, for this see:

[Determine which .NET Framework versions are installed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/how-to-determine-which-versions-are-installed)

That should help a bit but testing is needed, so I'm happy with the approximate result.